# Calculate the length of a Date/Time interval in days, hours, and minutes

Tags: datetime, ms-access-2013

I have created a table with a Start Date/time and an end Date/Time. Now I am trying to create a query that will calculate the difference between the Start date and the End date in Days, Hours, and Minutes. I am using Access 2013. I would like to do this in the table because in the end, I need to store the Days, Hours, and Minutes in a permanent record. However, I understand it's not good programming to do the calculation in the table. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: The question, I think, is _what_ are you going to do with the time difference. The problem with calculating it is you have to write a trigger in case the record is updated and it needs to be recalculated. I don't know if Access does that, probably does. In that case, you can cast theory aside and have the redundant column. The point is that date arithmetic can be expensive time-wise, so if you need that difference a lot, precalculate it. But if it isn't necessary, why bother? (You may also want to have a `VIEW` fronting the table, with the added calculated fields in the view only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do the calculations "in the table" you could use a Before Change data macro. For a table with

- Date/Time fields named [Started] and [Ended] to hold the start/end values, and
- Long Integer fields named [DurationDays], [DurationHours], and [DurationMinutes] to hold the calculated values,

the following macro might do the trick:

[image: BeforeChange.png]

For more information on Data Macros see

[Create a data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx)

Comment: Can I add a little twist to this. On my form I have a control called Start Date and a control called End Date. I have added 3 Controls Days, Hours, Minutes. How can I use what you showed me to populate that Days, Hours and Minutes controls upon exit of the End Date control?

Comment: If your Days, Hours, and Minutes controls are bound to the corresponding fields in the table then the values will be calculated by the Data Macro and appear in the controls, but only when you commit (save) the changes to the record. If you want the calculated values to appear in the controls *before* the changes are saved (while the form is still "dirty") then you'll need to add VBA code to perform the same calculations and assign the values to the controls' `.Value` properties, and call it from the appropriate event handlers in the form (perhaps the `On Lost Focus` event for the "End Date").

Comment: Here's the code I'm using. The day is working fine. The Hours and Minutes are comming back at 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Me.UnboundDays.Value = Int(Abs(Me.End_Date - Me.Start_Date))
dayFraction = (Abs(Me.End_Date - Me.Start_Date) - Int(Abs(Me.End_Date - Me.Start_Date)))
durHours = (Int(dayFraction * 24))
Me.UnBoundHours.Value = (durHours)
Me.UnBoundMinutes.Value = (Round(dayFraction * 1440 - durHours * 60, 0))